# Please help with this proof !!

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $b$ and $c$ be two integers not both zero. Let $a$ be an integer. If $a$ divides $b$ and $a$ divides $c$ then a divides $\gcd(b,c)$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\  $ By Bezout's identity, $\ \gcd(b,c) = j b + k c\ $ for $\,j,k\in\Bbb Z.\,$ This is divisible by any common divisor of $\,b,c,$ i.e. *linearly representable* common divisors are always *greatest* common divisors.